# a div for every two div of images using loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put a `<div title="Pages">` for every two lines of the code below, else would use  instead.

However, i wish to use a `<div title="Pages 1-2">` and `<div title="Pages 3-4">` and so on.

The code is not right even for the question on the first paragraph as i had tried it.

`document_images_list` prints the url of the images. (which is working ok)

```
<% @print.document_images_list.each do |image| %>
    <% if (1..2).each do |pages| %>
      <div title="Pages">
    <% else %>
      <div>
    <% end %>
      <%= image_tag image %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @print.document_images_list.each do |image| %>
  <div title="<%= cycle("Pages", "Pages", "")>
      <%= image_tag image %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

try this

Comment: I need one with <div title="Page"> and consequently without title such as <div> only. cycle looks like it works... but should i do:

<%= cycle(<div title="Pages">, <div>) %> instead?

How about having the numbers in the pages, like title Pages 1, then without title (a normal <div>) and then title page 2 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hackish but the following should work:

To simplify the code, let's assume `@images = @print.document_images_list`:

```
<% @images.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |images| %>
   <div title="Pages <%= "#{@images.index(images[0]).next}-#{@images.index(images[1]).next}" %>">
    <%= image_tag images[0] %>
    <%= image_tag images[1] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This will result in:

```
<div title="Pages 1-2">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</div>

<div title="Pages 3-4">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Which is what you're looking for if I understood correctly.